# Open url in system browser windows phon

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am making an html5 app for windows phone 8 and I have a link that is generated by JavaScript and passed into a frame.  I would like to put an open in browser button on the application bar.  With ios you can do this by adding the _system to the link is there an equivalent in WP?  Is there any way to open the browser without using the launcher or is there a way to get the JavaScript variable into the launcher?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Launchers to open and system application

Below is the sample code for the same:

```
   WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
   webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://msdn.microsoft.com", UriKind.Absolute);
   webBrowserTask.Show();
```

MSDN Reference:
[How to use the web browser task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394020%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah but the Uri is pre set I want to open a link that is generated by JavaScript.  Can I pull a variable into the launcher?

Comment: Yes, You can set the New URI on the button click.

Comment: this is my question.  How do I do this?